# How to set the default command, with options, to open a file on MacOS?

Tags: macos

I know how to a associate default application to open a particular file type. But I want to open a file with "command -option1 -option2" when I double-click in Finder or when I invoke "open" command on terminal. For example, I want to open all the text files using command "emacsclient -a emacs -c". How to do this on MacOS?

Comment: Would you accept using Automator to make a droplet to run your script when you drop a file? It’s not clear you can hijack the default launch path which doesn’t allow for variable injection afaik.

Comment: IF you make the Automator workflow an Application, you could set that as the default app for text files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an Apple/Shell script or Automator action. The Shell script can be put in a Wrapper like [Platypus](https://sveinbjorn.org/platypus), the Automator action can be clickable or even a service.

Comment: Despite being marked as solved, I have no idea, how to make this work on my computer.  In fact, it only copies the two comments given earlier but adds no real benefit